# How to copy selected items to a Data folder using powershell script?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

We have a requirement for bulk workflow approval. Where we need to add items(with or without children) similar to this image,

[image]

Following this article, https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/12/14/Multi-Item-Publish-with-Sitecore-Powershell-Extensions/,
I created a power shell module named "BulkApproval" as below,

[image]

and when I click on Start new batch I was able to create a directory in the Data folder, now I am not sure how to copy the selected items to the newly created folder.

How do I achieve this? Any guidance would be much helpful.

My script is as below,

```
$dataFolder = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::DataFolder
$rootFolder = $dataFolder + "\buckets"
$selectedItem = Get-Item -path .    
if($selectedItem -ne $null){
    $selectedItems = @()
    $newWorkflowName = Show-Input "Please provide a name for the new batch:" -MaxLength 20
    if($newWorkflowName -ne $null -and $newWorkflowName -ne ""){
        
        $selectedItems += $selectedItem
        if($selectedItem.Children.Length -gt 0){
                $includeChildrenPromptResult = Show-ModalDialog -Control "ConfirmChoice" -Parameters @{btn_0="Yes"; btn_1="No";  te="Include child items?"; cp="Create Batch and Add Item"} -Height 120 -Width 450
                if($includeChildrenPromptResult -eq "btn_0"){
                    $allChildItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $selectedItem.Paths.FullPath -Recurse
                    $selectedItems += $allChildItems
                   
                }
            }
    }
        #create a new directory here
        $newWorkflowPath = $rootFolder+"\"+$newWorkflowName
        Write-Host("$newWorkflowPath",$newWorkflowPath)
            Write-Host("New Item",$newWorkflowPath)
            New-Item -Path $newWorkflowPath -ItemType directory
ForEach ($item in $selectedItems) {
     Copy-Item -Path  $item.FullPath -Destination $newWorkflowPath
}   
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if you've considered all of your options, so please disregard this comment if you have! But, have you consider adding a new commands to the workbox, such as "Submit with children" & "Approve with children" to meet your requirements of "with or without children" the workbox supports without children out of the box.

Comment: The requirement is not to add it to workbox. I have already referred an article on Batching the workflow. But that was not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the item to specified path using Export-item command.