# Import-Item now working on other directory files

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have exported items using **Export-Item** command to a specific path in Data folder say, "websitepath/data/batch/userGivenName", please refer my previous question [How to copy selected items to a Data folder using powershell script?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31709/how-to-copy-selected-items-to-a-data-folder-using-powershell-script)
now I have to read the items from this folder. The items under folder are in **.item** extension.
I am able to get items using
`$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "websitepath\Data\batch\sample"`, but the items are not deserialized.

I tried using, **Import-Item** but its returning empty list, how do I deserialize/convert them?

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "websitepath\Data\buckets\sample"
$list=@();
$items|Foreach{
    $itemPath="websitepath\Data\buckets\sample\"+$_.BaseName
    $list+= Import-Item -Path $itemPath -Root "websitepath\Data\buckets\"
   Write-Host($list)
}
if($list.Count -eq 0) {
    
    Show-Alert "There are no items currently added to the batch."
    
} 
else {
 $list | Show-ListView 
   
}
Close-Window
```

I referred following file for Import-Item,
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/import-item-1

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Does the deserialization work using the Sitecore Ribbon commands? This will help determine if there is an issue with the script or something else.

Comment: I guess the issue is with the script, as I noticed the import-items created items under "Sitecore/Content" folder by default as the item path I have provided didnt match with sitecore content tree structure

Answer (score 0):

To test the same scenario, I did the following on my local.

- I created two items in the `content tree` like this.

[image]

- I exported the items using the `Export-Item`. And it looks like this

[image]

- I deleted the items in the `content tree` and then I run this command to import the items using `Import-Item` in `PowerShell` like this.

  `Import-Item -path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore10.1sc.dev.local\App_Data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\Home" -root "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore10.1sc.dev.local\App_Data\serialization\" -recurse`

And then it created those items in the content tree.

I think, if you want to import the items, In place of using a loop, you can use `recursive` and you need to provide the folder path from where you need to import the items. For example, I am exporting items inside the Home folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I didn't want the items to be created again in the content tree. I tried to  convert them back to item as they were in ".item" extension. I guess I have used the wrong command to achieve this. As the Import-Item created items under "Sitecore/Content" folder as the path provide doesn't match with the content structure.